# Capture value from function

Tags: python

I'm having trouble while trying to store the output of the function below, basically I'm trying to create a maths quiz which asks randomized basic math questions and then gives the ability to answer those questions while checking whether they are correct and was wondering if anyone was able to help me out with the code or provide me insight into what I need to learn in order to complete it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
print ("Hello to the maths quiz, what is your name?")
name = input()
from random import choice,randint

def rand_task1mathquiz():
    a,b = randint(0,10),randint(0,10)
    random_operations = choice(["+","-","/","*"])
    print("{0} {1} {2}".format(a,random_operations,b))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in range(10):
    rand_task1mathquiz()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the resulting expression from rand_task1mathquiz ? Pass it as a return value from the function.

Comment: rand_task1mathquiz outputs 10 random math questions generated from the by the computer and then I want to be able to store them in order to be able to answer them, I'm not actually sure whether storing them would be the right thing to do but basically Im trying to get the 10 random questions,be able to answer them then check whether they are correct.

Comment: So store them as array of strings for example.

Comment: im fairly new to python, could you possibly show me how i could do that especially with a function ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what this question has to do with storing the output of a function anywhere. If were formulated only to be focused on your question about Python-the-language, with nothing unrelated to functions and return values (random number selection has nothing to do with return values; prompting the user has nothing to do with return values; etc), it would be more clear what you really wanted to know.

Comment: Im just trying to find a way I would be able to answer the output given by the code above in a way that I would be able to check whether those answers are correct. Like i said IM NEW TO THIS STUFF.

Comment: @JakubN We understand that you're new, and there's nothing wrong with that. Everyone starts somewhere. But if you're so new to the subject that you can't articulate your question, that's not our fault. Your question, as it's currently phrased, is unclear and confusing. Perhaps you should go through [Google's Python Class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) or some similar tutorial and come back when you have a better understanding of functions and returning values so that you can more clearly explain what you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general pattern you are looking for is the `return` statement.  When you want to capture the return value of a function, typically, you'd assign the function's result to a variable, just as you assign static values to variables, except for the `()` on the right-hand side which makes it into a function call to be evaluted, rather than a reference to the function object.

Notice also how you were already doing this with the return values from the library functions `randint()`, `choice()`, `range()`, etc.

```
def rand_task1mathquiz():
    a,b = randint(0,10),randint(0,10)
    random_operations = choice(["+","-","/","*"])
    return("{0} {1} {2}".format(a,random_operations,b))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in range(10):
        quiz = rand_task1mathquiz()
        print quiz
        # Probably evaluate the returned value somehow, compare to user input
```

The changed division of labor here is also worth noting -- the function returns a value, and the caller prints it.  A useful function can run on its own, with no user interaction; input/output functionality should be kept separate from program logic as far as possible.

If you want to create a list of questions, that's easy now, too:

```
questions = list()
for x in range(10):
   questions.append(rand_task1mathquiz())
# Now do something with questions
```

or equivalently, but somewhat less readably, using a list comprehension:

```
questions = [rand_task1mathquiz() for _ in range(10)]
```

A further improvement might be to have the function return both the question and the answer; it makes sense to keep them both close together in the program code.

```
def rand_task():
    a,b = randint(0,10), randint(0, 10)
    ops = {'+': int.__add__, '-': int.__sub__,
        '/': int.__truediv__, '*': int.__mul__}
    random_operation = choice(list(ops.keys()))
    # Should still guard against op='/' with b==0
    return ops[random_operation](a, b), \
        '{0} {1} {2}'.format(a, random_operation, b)
```

... though using [`__add__` and friends](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) is probably too tricky to properly understand just yet.  It certainly beats `eval` in terms of security, so perhaps you should try it.

Comment: Hey I came back to see how I could improve the eval and before didn't see the int.__add__ suggestion you made as it seemed too advanced but also I noticed you made the program display the output in the list and when I print the question the answer shows up before it and I actually wanted to prevent that, from analysing your code I'm kinda lost how i could remove that certain feature

Comment: The function returns two values. Don't print the first. Or make it only return the second.